# encoding jpeg in java without disk writing

Tags: java, jpeg, encode

as the title say i need to find some java jpeg encoder (it's good both source code or external library) that given an array that represent a raw pixel image or a BufferedImage can encode it **without writing** anything on file and return the encoded image possibly trough an array of some kind, with at least possibility to choose image quality and possibly with good efficiency.

NB: the array/image type input required (byte, int, argb, rgb, bgr, yuv...) doesn't matter for me, i can make approppriate conversions

Comment: What is the end goal here?  Are you trying to pass the encoded jpeg over a network?

Comment: You can simply use `ImageIO` to write the `BufferedImage` into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and finally obtain the byte array from this stream...

Comment: 1) i need to crypting image before it is written, because if i encode crypted bytes (since jpeg is a lossy format) i will be unable to decrypt back, so i need to perform jpeg encoding before of crypting.       

__2) is possible to avoid writing on file using ImageIO? i trought not, and if it's possibile how i can retrieve array from OutputStream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments: You can use the [`ImageIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class, and use it to write to a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html). The code could really be as simple as this:

```
private static byte[] getJpgData(BufferedImage image)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

This will **NOT** write the image to a disc or so. It will only write the image into a memory block, which you can then process or manipulate further.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a stream of bytes, then use Java's built in methods.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream)

```
ImageIO.write(myImage, "format", myOutputStream);
```

Comment: doesn't it write image as file? i need that no output write will be performed. and if it can avoid writing using that method, how i retrieve array from OutputStream?

Comment: It writes to the output stream you pass in. Just don't use a file output stream.  Use a ByteArrayOutputStream and you'll have a stream of bytes representing the image and no file will be written.